# Specify a database on command line Subsonic

Tags: oracle, subsonic, sharpdevelop

Hi guys
I was trying to create a connection with these settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
     <configSections>
    <section name="SubSonicService"
             type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" 
             requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SamConnection"
            connectionString='Password=myPass;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myAdmUsr;Data Source=myServer;'
            providerName="OLEDB.Oracle.1" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <SubSonicService defaultProvider="SamConnection">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="SamConnection" 
             type="SubSonic.OracleDataProvider, SubSonic"
             connectionStringName="SamConnection"
             generatedNamespace="myNameSpace"/>
    </providers>
  </SubSonicService>
</configuration>
```

but with the command line: sonic generate  /db myDB /out Generated
the code generated is the first DB on server and not from myDB I was trying to specify the connection string in the DB but did not work, where can I specify this?

PS: i'm using sharpdevelop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either modify your tnsnames.ora file to use your database as a default schema or set the ORACLE_SID environment variable before running subcommander.

Or, according to connectionstrings.com, you can use this syntax to connect to a db without using the tnsnames.ora file at all: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle

```
Data Source=username/password@myserver//instancename;
```

but you have to enable `EZCONNECT` in sqlnet.ora:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```